# header php проблема

Tags: php, header

когда я переходу по ссылке типа
http://site.ru/counter.php?url=http://download.ru/file.exe?g=1

меня кидает на файл counter.php

```
if ($_GET['g'] == 1) 
{
     header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
     $file = fopen("./counter/1.txt", "a+");
     flock($file, LOCK_EX); 
     $count = fread($file, 100);
     $count++; 
     ftruncate($file, 0); 
     fwrite($file, $count); 
     flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
     fclose($file); 
}
```

где счетчик работает

но проблема с header, не могу сделать чтобы кидало на страницу к файлу, как я только не пробовал...
прошу подскажите

Comment: перенеси header в конец if и убедись что у тебя правильный $_GET['url']

Comment: Ещё в Location должен быть полный URL - `http://site.ru/bla/bla/bla/file.exe`.

Comment: Так же перед `fclose()` не забудьте сделать `fflush($file);`.

Comment: if ($_GET['g'] == 1) 
    {
     
         $file = fopen("./counter/1.txt", "a+");
         flock($file, LOCK_EX); 
         $count = fread($file, 100);
         $count++; 
         ftruncate($file, 0); 
         fwrite($file, $count); 
         flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
         fclose($file);
         fflush($file);
         header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);

    }

сделал так все равно пустой белый экран без редиректа

Comment: у меня url под множество ссылок сделан по несколько в каждой статье сайта

мне бы чтото универсальное надо чтобы не копировать n раз этот кусок php кода в couter.php

Comment: ошибка была в ссылке, надо было не `?url=`

а `&url=`